# Access several functions from a file using parent directory

Tags: python

Say I have a folder `Dir` with several files `Funs_1`, `Funs_2` each of which contain several functions with unique names. Structure is as such:

```
project
│   foo.py
└───Dir
       Funs_1 >> some_function_1
       Funs_2 >> some_function_2
```

How can I call `some_function_1` and `some_function_2` from the project file `foo.py` using `Dir.Funs_1.some_function_1` or something of that nature?

Comment: You have to import them.

Comment: In essence you need to first import the files from the directory `from Dir import Funs_1, Funs_2`, and then call the functions from the imported names: `Funs_1.some_function_1(*args, **kwargs)`, `Funs_2.some_function_2(*args, **kwargs)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you can simply import the file from the directory and then access the functions:

```
from Dir import Funs_1, Funs_2
Funs_1.some_function_1()
Funs_2.some_function_2()
```

Alternatively:

```
import Dir.Funs_1, Dir.Funs_2
Dir.Funs_1.some_function_1()
Dir.Funs_2.some_function_2()
```